# How to set wildcard in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] possible?

Tags: php

is it possible to set $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to a wildcard, so that anyone on the network can see this?

```
<?php


if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "112.200.150.212"){

                ?>
                <a href="http://www.tinycounter.com" target="_blank" title="free hit counter"><img border="0" alt="free hit counter" src="http://mycounter.tinycounter.com/index.php?user=fortressgate"></a>

                <?php
                }?>
```

but i want the network can see the counter... so it would look like this?

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "112.200.150.%")
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two solutions:

```
$chk = "112.200.150.";
if( substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],0,strlen($chk)) == $chk)
```

OR:

```
if( preg_match("(^112\.200\.150\.)",$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "112.200.150.") === 0)
```

Comment: instead of checking for `!== false`, you should check for `=== 0`.  It should only match at the *beginning* of the string.

Comment: @Gian: This works for me; and it is (IMHO) the best solution.  (+1)

Comment: hahah that's why it didnt work.. so sorry.. bout that... hehe